# Redirecting from https://example.com to https://www.example.com in htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website with the ssl for www.example.com. I have set up a htaccess redirect which redirects the user from http://example.com => http://www.example.com.
If I enter https://www.example.com then it works. But if I enter https://example.com then it gives me a ssl error.

How do I redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com without showing the ssl error?

I use the following code in my htaccess to redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Contact your SSL provider and ask them to add SubjectAltName for the apex.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to your SSL setup, probably its not set for (*.domain.com) if so (www.domain.com) doesn't issues any error.

`www.domain.com != domain.com`

Because `www` is subdomain, that redirected to (`domain.com`), then, you need to enable SSL for (`*.domain.com`) or just for (`www.domain.com`) as suggested by @Jack

Comment: Just domain.com and www.domain.com will do, certificates for *.domain.com are more expensive and in most cases quite unnecessary.