# How to redirect https://sitename.com to https://www.sitename.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My redirect in htaccess file successfully redirects example.com to https://www.example.com

but if I type: https://example.com in the address bar, I am not redirected.

Current code looks a bit like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.local$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !.cms.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Adding the www after the https:// does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you have a wildcard SSL?

Comment: No I dont. I dont have any subdomains.Thanks

Comment: I have had issues where the SSL looks at example.com as a subdomain of www.example.com.  This may not be an issue for you, but I have had it before.

Comment: Here is another post with info on the issue:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18886890/2547075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also redirect `https://example.com` to  `https://www.example.com` You need to have your rule like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Let me know how that works out.

Comment: Yes I want https:// domain to redirect to https:// www domain I tried adding the rules above, but it did not work. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? Did you get an error or did it just not do anything. Clear your cache and try again or try in another browser. The rules do in fact work.