# Redirect https://example.com/ to https://www.example.com/ without changing httpd.conf

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i bought a normal ssl (DV ssl) for my site www.example.com
i created ssl on cpanel  with no problem.
so i added these lines in .htaccess and my website works to https very nice.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

ok here is my problem :
this ssl works just for https://www.example.com (bought for just 1 address) so if every body type in browser https://example.com would get certificate error!
i googled so much and find that i must create a virtualhost in httpd.conf to bypass certificate error.
something like this code:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/apache2/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/apache2/server.key
  SSLEngine on
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}      [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

but i can't change in httpd.conf because my site works on a shared hosting.
so i phoned to hosting admin and ask him to create a virtualhost for me but no success!!
how could i solve this problem? I would appreciate to anyone solve it.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886821/redirecting-from-https-example-com-to-https-www-example-com-in-htacess

Comment: no success because my cert. works just for 1 address and wildcard cert. are so expensive.

Comment: Why don't you just force WWW on example.com?

Comment: it's very rare but if someone typed in browser h t t p s://example.com it will get certificate error! i want every body type manually h t t p s ://eample.com or h t t p s://www.example.com get no error. i don't have any problem with http my problem is about https typed manually in browser

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is for www.example.com and not for example.com you will always get a certificate warning when trying to access `https://example.com` because the hostname in the URL does not match the subject(s) of the certificate.

This is simply how certificate validation works and there is no change to httpd.conf, no redirection, no DNS CNAME, no tricks, no whatever which will help you solve this issue. Your **only choice is to have a certificate which also matches example.com** and there are several CA which offer you free certificates for this case.

Comment: tnx Steffen this is what i am afraid about it but i think ur right. and now the question is could i upload 2 SSL on a cpanel for www and non www without buing a wildcard cert. ?

Comment: @shakib: I have no knowledge of cpanel and apart from that this is  a different question than your original one so I recommend to ask it as new question if you don't find the solution in the documentation. Apart from that you don't even need a wildcard cert but just one which includes www.example.com and example.com and like I said several CA give you such certs for free.